# interval depending on sample size

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, tolerance-interval

I came across these funnel plots [here](https://understandinguncertainty.org/three-fold-variation-uk-bowel-cancer-death-rates) and tried to reproduce something similar where I have a normally distributed population and I happen to know the true population mean (500000) and standard deviation (13000).

I am aware of these 2 intervals: confidence interval (CI) and tolerance interval. The former's width depends on the sample size whereas the latter's depends on the sample size and the variance in the population.

I came up with the R code below. It produces the following graph.

[image]

IMHO the blue line represents the 95% CI depending on the sample size. In other words, the sample mean will fall with 95% probability into this funnel. Would you agree with this?

```
mu_ <- 500000
sd_ <- 13000
z_value <- qnorm(.975)
max_sample_size = 100
repeats = 2

results <- NULL
upper_and_lower <- NULL

for (sample_size_ in 3:max_sample_size) {
    
    for (sample_number_ in 1:2) {
        
        sample_ <- rnorm(sample_size_, mean=mu_, sd=sd_)
        
        df <- data.frame(
            sample_size = sample_size_
            , mean = mean(sample_)
        )

        results <- rbind(results, df)
        
    }
    
    df <- data.frame(
        sample_size = sample_size_
        , upper = mu_ + (z_value * (sd_/sqrt(sample_size_)))
        , lower = mu_ - (z_value * (sd_/sqrt(sample_size_)))
    )
    upper_and_lower <- rbind(upper_and_lower, df)
}

ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=results, aes(y = mean, x = sample_size)) +
    geom_line(data=upper_and_lower, aes(y = upper, x = sample_size), color = "blue", size=2) +
    geom_line(data=upper_and_lower, aes(y = lower, x = sample_size), color = "blue", size=2) +
    ggplot() +
geom_point(data=results, aes(y = mean, x = sample_size)) +
geom_line(data=upper_and_lower, aes(y = upper, x = sample_size), color = "blue", size=2) +
geom_line(data=upper_and_lower, aes(y = lower, x = sample_size), color = "blue", size=2) +
theme(
    axis.text.x=element_text(size=18, angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1, face="bold", color="black"),
    axis.text.y=element_text(size=18, face="bold", color="black"),
    axis.title.x=element_text(size=18, face="bold", color="black"),
    axis.title.y=element_text(size=18, face="bold", color="black")
) +
ylab("Sample Means \t\n Red dotted line = population mean") +
geom_hline(yintercept=mu_, linetype="dotted", color = "red", size=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly correct to say the blue curves represent the 95% CIs. For a given sample size, the 95% CI would be different for every different observed mean. But, it is correct that any mean will fall within the blue curves with 95% probability.